# Disable preview stage for offer in Azure's Cloud Partner Portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We use the Cloud Partner Portal to manage the status of our offers.

The publishing process includes a preview stage where qualification can be made for the offer.
To advance to the next stage, I have to manually select the *Go live* option.

I would like to skip this stage (also know as the preview stage) and go live directly, without having to manually go through this step.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview page is where publishers can specify the audience to have access to their offer preview, to verify that the offer meets all your requirements before it goes live.

Currently, the option to directly publish the offer to Live is **not** available.

Comment: Thanks, it does seem that way. Do you know if there is some documentation which states that? The reason I would like to *disable* the preview is that I would like to automate the whole process of publishing. The preview stage means that I have to check one way or another whether the offer was ready to go live. Do you perhaps have any suggestions on how I can get notified when the offer is ready to go live, maybe through a pub-sub approach?

Comment: There is no documentation as of now. I internally checked with the team and you wil get to know immediately after you click go live.

Comment: Okay, thanks for doing that. Do you have any suggestions on my second question? Do you know if its possible to "subscribe" to the events in the Azure marketplace in order to detect that the offer is in the preview state? As opposed to doing something like polling, for instance.

Comment: I have addressed the new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842232/subscribe-to-cloud-partner-portal-through-azure-event-grid). I would appreciate it if you could take a look there too.