# Subscribe to Azure Cloud Partner Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am trying to automate the offer publishing process on Azure Cloud Partner Portal.

I would like to get notified when the offer reaches the preview stage.
One way to do this would be to deploy a serverless function which polls the cloudpartner api to check the status of the offer.

I was wondering if there was a cleaner solution to this problem though. 
I have been reading about Event Grid at the following page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview

It seems like there is a possibility to configure an event source if the event is *within* the subscription, but this event is *not* in the subscription but rather at the Cloud Partner Portal level.

Is it possible to achieve what I am looking for with a pub-sub model?

Comment: have a look at the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342241/handle-blob-events-from-storage-accounts-in-multiple-azure-subscriptions-in-diff

Comment: @Roman Thanks for the link. I read through it but am I not right in saying that is only for subscription events? Such as a resource group

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do this. When they publish the offer in the Partner Center  and once the offer is in preview, publishers get notified by email

Comment: I'm integrating this in a fully automated build system. Checking whether an email is received does not seem like the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Cloud Partner Portal (CPP) REST APIs allow only notification via the [e-mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal-orig/cloud-partner-portal-api-publish-offer), there is no publishing to the weebhook endpoint.

The workaround for that notification is using a 3r party e-mail integrator, for instance: *Zapier*.

The following screen snippet shows how easy can be integrated the Azure CPP to the Azure Event Grid using the Zapier. The notification e-mail can be used also direct to *zapiermail.com*.

[image]

Note, that also can be used an *Azure Logic App* instead of *Zapier* as an integrator, see the following screen snippet:

[image]

Comment: This sounds really neat, thanks! I will look into it tomorrow. I am going to wait to close the question to see if other users have other suggestions.

Comment: I have tested an email notification with Zapier (both using a google.com and direct zapiermail.com) and also with the Azure Logic Apps. Note, that the request must be wrapped by Array for webhook and the Custom Topic Endpoint must be created for input schema = *CustomEventSchema*

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help. I am trying to setup the Azure Logic App, but I see an error "Create and authorize OAuth connection failed". Did you ever see this? I am using Outlook as an email provider.

Comment: Try to use trigger for a new email arrives @gmail.com. It's straightforward declaration.